# Chef sanity check on deployed app

Tags: java, tomcat, chef-infra

I am using AWS Opsworks that uses Chef to deploy a java application (war file)

The problem is that the chef recipe completes but when that happens tomcat is set to restart.

So, there is a period between when the deployment appears successful and the app is actually available.

And the tomcat restart may also fail in that period.

Is there a cookbook to ping a specific url with a timeout and consider the chef run successful only if the ping is successful?

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to your recipe code:

```
ruby_block 'wait for tomcat' do
  block do
    until (Chef::HTTP.new('http://localhost').get('/') rescue false)
      sleep(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Or something like that.

Comment: You may also want a timeout on that so that it will not run forever if there is an issue.

Comment: https://github.com/poise/jenkins/blob/master/libraries/jenkins.rb#L185-L197 is a more complete example, but yeah a timeout can be good.